# C# Static event not fired

Tags: c#, events, static, null

I am doing some kind of status reporting so I can update the new status to the UI. For e.g. the status can be - "Loading...", "Loaded..." and so on. My problem is that the StatusChanged event is always null and can't be fired.

```
public class StatusReporter
{
    public delegate void StatusChangedEventHandler(Status status);

    public static event StatusChangedEventHandler StatusChanged;

    private static Status status;

    public static Status CurrentStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return status;
        }
        set
        {
            status = value;
            OnStatusChange();
        }
    }

    private static void OnStatusChange()
    {
        if (StatusChanged != null)
        {
            StatusChanged(status);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That means no one has subscribed to your event.

Comment: And how are you adding handlers to the event...?

Comment: I have subscribed to the event from the MainWindow class and that's why I don't know what's happening. 

  StatusReporter.StatusChanged += new StatusReporter.StatusChangedEventHandler(StatusReporter_StatusChanged);

Comment: There are pretty few situations where static events are appropriate. I suspect this isn't own of them.

Comment: So I should maybe change the whole structure of the class?

Comment: What you've posted looks ok. Use a debugger to confirm that your code to subscribe to the event is being called before you try to raise the event. Check that you aren't unsubscribing anywhere. (aside: Consider making the class static as well)

Answer (score 1):

The code:

```
public class StatusReporter {
    public delegate void StatusChangedEventHandler(Status status);
    public static event StatusChangedEventHandler StatusChanged;

    public static Status CurrentStatus {
        set {
            StatusReporter.OnStatusChange(status=value);
        }

        get {
            return StatusReporter.status;
        }
    }

    static void OnStatusChange(Status status) {
        if(null!=StatusChanged)
            StatusReporter.StatusChanged(status);
    }

    static Status status;
}
```

The test:

```
partial class Form1 {
    static void Form1_StatusChange(Status status) {
        Debug.Print("status changed");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        StatusReporter.StatusChanged+=Form1_StatusChange;
        StatusReporter.CurrentStatus=new Status(); // assumed, you don't show the Status class
    }
}
```

Although I don't understand why all *static*.

Comment: I found out what was the problem. It was not from the class.

Comment: @NikolayDakov: What was not from the class?

Comment: The status was being changed before the event subscription.

Comment: Oh. Anyway, this is my answer and I've tested. Wish it helps, not necessarily accept it.